# Linux: Batch rename multiple files to parent dir + suffix in order of name

Tags: linux, rename

I need to batch rename multiple images and want to use the parent directory as base name. To prevent one overwriting the other, a suffix must be added. The order of the renaming process musts follow the timestamp of the file. Because the 'first' file is a featured image for the site I'm using it for.

Tree:

```
└── main
├── white tshirt
│   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   ├── IMG_2.jpg
│   ├── IMG_3.jpg
│   └── IMG_4.jpg
├── black tshirt
│   ├── IMG_1.jpg
│   ├── IMG_2.jpg
│   ├── IMG_3.jpg
│   └── IMG_4.jpg
└── red tshirt
    ├── IMG_1.jpg
    ├── IMG_2.jpg
    ├── IMG_3.jpg
    └── IMG_4.jpg
```

Goal:

```
└── main
├── white tshirt
│   ├── white-tshirt-1.jpg
│   ├── white-tshirt-2.jpg
│   ├── white-tshirt-3.jpg
│   └── white-tshirt-4.jpg
├── black tshirt
│   ├── black-tshirt-1.jpg
│   ├── black-thisrt-2.jpg
│   ├── black-tshirt-3.jpg
│   └── black-tshirt-4.jpg
└── red tshirt
    ├── red-tshirt-1.jpg
    ├── red-tshirt-2.jpg
    ├── red-tshirt-3.jpg
    └── red-tshirt-4.jpg
```

Replacing spaces with dashes is not required, but preferred. Platform: Debian 8

Comment: Have you considered hiring a programmer?

Comment: Is there a place where you can hire programmers for code snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the job:

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir in *; do
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    cd "$dir"

    pref=$(echo "$dir" | tr ' ' -)

    i=1
    ls -tr | while read f; do
        ext=$(echo "$f" | sed 's/.*\.//')
        mv "$f" "${pref}-${i}.$ext"
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
    done

    cd ..
done
```

Invoke the script inside your main directory and make sure there are only your target folders in it. Also make sure your files'names do not contain the character '\'

Comment: That will probably fail if any of the filenames contain spaces.

Comment: That looks like it will fail if any of the filenames contain backslashes (or end with backslashes?).

Comment: Well yeah, it would, I could modify it further to avoid that case too, but actually... he shouldn't have backslashes in his filenames in the first place, it leads to all sorts of problems.

Comment: tested but it won't retain the extension

Comment: I keep forgetting trivial stuff... try now

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot.